# Install dropbox over browser VNC

Tags: firefox, vnc, dropbox

I want to install dropbox, but I only have access to firefox over VNC.

Comment: I don't think that you can install any application from Firefox. Maybe [Dropfox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/dropfox/?src=search) can help you somehow.

Comment: Are you trying to install dropbox on the remote machine, where you are just able to use Firefox, or do you want to install dropbox on your client, which is unfortunally only connected to the remote host through vpn, so you problem is how to get downloaded dropbox from the remote firefox to your client pc?

Comment: Install dropbox on the remote machine

Comment: My guess is that you do not have any privileges on the remote machine to install Software. Is it a windows or a linux remote? Nevertheless I presume you have no chance at all if you do not have admin rights on the remote (dropbox needs admin rights badly to install)..

Comment: ***Please re-state question:*** You only have access to remote host over browser-based VNC session, or you have VNC access (but only to run Firefox), or something else .. *This is too vague to answer.* Also, what **Ubuntu** version?

Answer (score 1):

Installation of any program requires at least sudo right access (or root) and you should have the right to access apt-get or aptitude installers to perform the operation. While having access only to Firefox (no matter how) you can do only browsing.